# App don't work correctly on another Computer

Tags: windows, driver, converters, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I've two PC with dual monitors, with the same configuration (USB to VGA converter, same USB port, same VGA port on the second monitor), same drivers, same version, same Windows (Seven Professional), sames monitors with sames resolution, **same** on everything I know how to access to.

I've an app on which when I **`click`** `on a button -->` **`display another maximized window`**.

On the **first** PC, the app work **correctly**, the other maximized window display in full screen on the **second monitor**.

On the **second** PC, the app **doesn't work correctly** ! ):

When I **`click on the button`** the other maximized window just open (maximized) on the **first monitor**, the principal where the app is displayed (as same as the first PC).

So I've tried to

- change the screen order (put 1 on left of 2 or 2 on left of 1)
- check if the drivers have a problems, but no (no warning or interrogation sign in the *"Uninstall a program"* program
- change size resolution on both screens but nothing
- un-maximize the second window's app and close it on the correct screen, nothing, the window just maximize and display on the bad screen like before

Sooooooo I've no idea of where the problem could came...

Sorry if my English is bad and thanks in advance for your answers you're my last resort.

Have a nice day

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/change-which-monitor-an-application-appears-on/457be45d-d0b8-4704-86ce-a13f8879b7c6

Comment: @LeonardKlausmann I didn't follow your link, because I can read "*windows xp*" on it, and OP talks about "*windows seven professional*". Knowing that, is it still worth clicking?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work and it seems that some options write in different answers have been deleted in Windows 7